# Sending and F5 to firefox

Tags: c#, firefox, sendkeys

I know this has most likely been asked before but I don't seem to be able to get it working.

I have a simple bit of code that starts a Firefox browser using a browser profile. This works great.

```
url_filename = "http://www.dxsummit.fi/#/?include=" + str_freq;               
Process pcs = new Process();
pcs.StartInfo.FileName = "firefox.exe";
pcs.StartInfo.Arguments = "-P DXSummit " + url_filename;
pcs.Start();
```

what I want to do is have the Firefox browser now do a refresh (F5).
I have tried various options but with no luck.

If I try

```
var hWnd = pcs.MainWindowHandle;
SwitchToThisWindow(hWnd, true);
SendKeys.Send("{F5}");
```

it gets an error as it can not find the MainWindowHandle.

I have also tried

```
IntPtr hWnd = pcs.Handle;
SwitchToThisWindow(hWnd, true);
SendKeys.Send("{F5}");
```

this does NOT give me an error but does NOT do anything either

Does anyone have any ideas ????

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the API function:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

But it will not steal the focus either but will only blink orange in the taskbar . But when the focus is in the browser you can use `SendWait` instead as

```cs
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{F5}");
```

or you can use the [Robot.cs](https://gist.github.com/Killercodes/5ff6cdbbb46391fdb0d5ae1e5b504284)